# How to return values of its order?

Tags: r, order

I have a matrix like this:

```
   10 0.646519601   0   0.085929349 0.255477717 0.012073334
   40 0.138403594   0   0.065979943 0.776693742 0.018922721
```

I want to keep the first column, and get rest numbers sorted by row. The result should be like this:

```
   10 5 1 2 4 3  #0.64 is the largest; 0 is the smallest in the row#
   40 4 1 3 5 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `rank` function row-wise, e.g.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
10 0.646519601   0   0.085929349 0.255477717 0.012073334
40 0.138403594   0   0.065979943 0.776693742 0.018922721
"))

R> cbind(dat[, 1], t(apply(dat[, -1], 1, rank)))
        V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
[1,] 10  5  1  3  4  2
[2,] 40  4  1  3  5  2
```

Comment: Thanks. Two more concerns. 1. What does the "t" mean? a new matrix? 2. The first "1" means the first column; the second "1" means "row-wise". Right?

Comment: 1. `t` returns the transposed matrix (see ?t in R); 2. correct